# How to show zomming in of a image within one subplot (On-figure magnifier)

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have an image. I want to show the zooming in region in the image.

For example, I have two region of interesting (ROI): red and yellow regions. The "red zooming image" should show above of the original image and the "yellow zooming image" should be shown below of original image.

To show them in the one subplot, I combine three image (two zooming images and the original image) into a row image. The combined image should be shown in subplot. The below figure shows what I expect. My issue is these zooming images can not zoom in first row and last row of combined image. Could you help me to do it? This is what I tried

```
 Img = imread('peppers.png');
 Img=rgb2gray(Img);
 Img=double(Img);
 Img=imresize(Img,[256 256]);
 %%Draw rectangle
 red_rect=[100 50 20 20];
 yellow_rect=[200 100 20 20];
 %% zoom in image
 red_Img_zoomIn=Img(red_rect(2) : (red_rect(2)+red_rect(4)) , red_rect(1) : (red_rect(1)+red_rect(3)) , :);
 yellow_Img_zoomIn=Img(yellow_rect(2) : (yellow_rect(2)+yellow_rect(4)) , yellow_rect(1) : (yellow_rect(1)+yellow_rect(3)) , :);
startrow = 30;
startcol = 30;
Img_zoom1=zeros(size(Img));
red_Img_zoomIn_original=red_Img_zoomIn;
red_Img_zoomIn=imresize(red_Img_zoomIn,10);
Img_zoom1(startrow:startrow+size(red_Img_zoomIn,1)-1,startcol:startcol+size(red_Img_zoomIn,2)-1) = red_Img_zoomIn;
Img_combined=[Img_zoom1;Img;zeros(size(Img))];
 %% Adding zooming images in Img_combined-centering
figure(1);
set(gcf,'color','w');
subplot(121);imshow(Img_combined,[]);
subplot(122);imshow(red_Img_zoomIn_original,[]);
```

This is my expected result.

[image]

Comment: You didn't combine the images... Img_conbined has zeroes... did you tried to do this? Do you want the rectangles drawn? did you try to draw them? I feel that is quite easy to help you, but it seems you didnt put much effort to this code.... Maybe Im wrong, but If that is the case, please give better description of specifically what is what you dont know how to do.

Comment: I have no idea to combine. Because if I combine or resize the zoom image. It will break pixel information. I have one code to do it as my update

Comment: When you say "It will break pixel information" you mean that if you resize, the pixel values will change? They MUST change, as zooming is adding more pixels to the image.

Comment: Yes. I add completed code. I sue red_Img_zoomIn=imresize(red_Img_zoomIn,5);
 to zoom in Image. The pixel looks like as blur. If I show directly by imshow, the image information look better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your zooming is the interpolation method. If you dont specify, `imresize` will use bilinear interpolation, effectively "blurring" your image.

To avoid that, explicitly specify the method you want, nearest neighbor, a method that duplicates the nearest pixel value. Note that there is also a way of telling `imresize` the exact amount of rows and columns you want the output image to have, insteadof just a scale.

If you add this piece of code to yours:

```
 red_Img_zoomIn=Img(red_rect(2) : (red_rect(2)+red_rect(4)) , red_rect(1) : (red_rect(1)+red_rect(3)) , :);
 yellow_Img_zoomIn=Img(yellow_rect(2) : (yellow_rect(2)+yellow_rect(4)) , yellow_rect(1) : (yellow_rect(1)+yellow_rect(3)) , :);

 % We need to rezise the pieces of the image if they want to be seen "big"


 % lets use nearest neighbour interpolation to make sure new pixel are just "repeated values"
red_Img_zoomOut=imresize(red_Img_zoomIn,'OutputSize',[size(Img,1) size(Img,2)],'Method','nearest');
yellow_Img_zoomOut=imresize(yellow_Img_zoomIn,'OutputSize',[size(Img,1) size(Img,2)],'Method',  'nearest');



% Combine images
 Img_combined=[red_Img_zoomOut;
      Img;
     yellow_Img_zoomOut];
 %% Adding zooming images in Img_combined-centering
 figure(1);
 set(gcf,'color','w');
imshow(Img_combined);
```

the output will be unblurred:

[image]

Comment: @user8264 glad to help! Consider accepting the answer then ;)

Comment: Sorry, it missing something. I need add the black color in the first row and last row. Besides, It need to add rectangular in there

Comment: @user8264 thats a different question, but I'm sure you can do it easily ;). Just reduce the amount of rows and cols from `OutputSize` in `imresize` and then add it to a black image!